# how to read an complex array in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

How to read the array below. For example i would like to set the 'actual_cash' to some other value. PLease help I am new to PhP.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Cashups[0]['actual_cash'] = 50.22;
```

To change the first instance of actual_cash.

```
$Cashups[1]['actual_cash'] = 100.22;
```

To chance the second instance, and so on.

To loop through this array, you can do something like:

```
foreach($Cashups as &$c)
{
  $c['actual_cash']=500.00;
}
```

Which would change al the actual_cash instances to 500.00

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach to iterate array

```
foreach($Cashups as $key => $value)
{
  $value['actual_cash']='newval';
}
```

if you have only two items in array you could also do this

```
$Cashups[0]['actual_cash']='someval';
$Cashups[1]['actual_cash']='someval';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($Cashups as $item){
  $item['actual_cash'] = $mynewvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using **for** loop:

```
 for($i = 0; $i < count($Cashups); $i++) {
       $Cashups[$i]['actual_cash'] = $yourValue;
    }
```

using **foreach** loop:

```
foreach($Cashups as &$c) {
   $c['actual_cash'] = $yourValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
foreach($Cashups as &$cashup){
// referencing $cashup to change it's value
 $cashup = 'new value';
}
```